# How to run dramatiq tasks run in detach mode?

Tags: python, dramatiq

I'm new with `dramatiq` and I do not find a way how to start `dramatiq` in detach mode like Celery?

I try to start with flags --d --detach, but nothing works.

Please inform me how to start dramatic in detach mode when I start `dramatiq app:broker`

Answer (score 0):

I found it's already work on detach mode, but if you wish to read the logs you need to have your terminal in open view